# subtracting from value in a text file, then outputting the calculation (C++)

Tags: c++, file, function

Hi I am working on a wage application with four options which are as follows:

1.Subtracts an amount from the shop bank account (The account is text file "shop"). You do not need to add the same amount to another account but you should record the transaction with a timestamp in a separate file. The application should prevent the account balance from becoming overdrawn.

2.List the five most recent transactions to the screen. If there haven’t yet been five transactions then list all of them.

3.Print the account name, number and current balance to the screen.

4.Exit the program.

I have completed 1,3 and 4 but I am completely stumped as to how to go about number 2. I was hoping someone would be able to help me as to how to go about this.

```
int read_balance(void);
void write_balance(int balance);
using namespace std;
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int selection;
    int total;
    int attempts = 0;
    string name;
    string number;
    cout << "Correct login details entered!"
         << "" << endl;
    cout << "1. Transfer an amount" << endl;
    cout << "2. List recent transactions" << endl;
    cout << "3. Display account details and current balance" << endl;
    cout << "4.Quit" << endl;
    cout << "Please enter menu number" << endl;
    cin >> selection;
    switch (selection)
    {
        case 1:
            cout << "How much do you wish to transfer?" << endl;
            int amount = 0;
            if (std::cin >> amount)
            {
                std::cout << "Transferred Amount:" << amount << "\n";
                int balance = read_balance();
                if (amount <= 0)
                {
                    std::cout << "Amount must be positive\n";
                }
                else if (balance < amount)
                {
                    std::cout << "Insufficient funds\n";
                }
                else
                {
                    int new_balance = balance - amount;
                    write_balance(new_balance);
                    std::cout << "New account balance: " << new_balance
                              << std::endl;
                    fstream infile("time.txt", ios::app);
                    std::time_t result = std::time(nullptr);
                    std::string timeresult = std::ctime(&result);
                    infile << amount << std::endl;
                    infile << timeresult << std::endl;
                }
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << "Here are you're recent transactions" << endl;
            break;
        case 3:
            cout << "The account names is:" << name << endl;
            cout << "The account number is:" << number << endl;
            std::cout << "The current account balance is " << read_balance()
                      << std::endl;
            break;
        case 4:
            system("pause");
            return 0;
        default:
            cout << "Ooops, invalid selection!" << endl;
            break;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
int read_balance(void)
{
    std::ifstream f;
    f.exceptions(std::ios::failbit | std::ios::badbit);
    f.open("shop.txt");
    int balance;
    f >> balance;
    f.close();
    return balance;
}
void write_balance(int balance)
{
    std::ofstream f;
    f.exceptions(std::ios::failbit | std::ios::badbit);
    f.open("shop.txt");
    f << balance;
    f.close();
}
```

Comment: what is your target platform and the compiler that you are using ?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio. And I'm not even sure what you mean by target platform, very new to this

Comment: You'll probably have to store transactions in memory.  Have you covered container classes in your class yet?

Comment: no we haven't covered that yet. Guess I'll have to look into container classes now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what should go in your 2nd switch case:

```
case 2:
{
    std::cout << "Here are your recent transactions" << '\n';

    for (int i = 0, size = v.size(); i < (size <= 5 ? size : 5); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << i << ". " << v.at(i) << '\n';
    }

    break;
}
```

Comment: getting this error when I try that:  error C2360: initialization of 'in' is skipped by 'case' label

Comment: @user3057816 I'm not getting this error. Do you mind giving me an example on [Coliru](http://stacked-crooked.com)?

Comment: Not even sure I understand the question. An example of what exactly? Sorry, I hate needing everything spelled out for me

Comment: Actually I was making a silly mistake. Your code is working now but the output is just the balance currently in the "shop" file, as oppose to actual transactions

Comment: @user3057816 Where are you storing the transactions?

Comment: I'm not as I said I'm completely stumped I don't even know where to begin with no.2

Comment: @user3057816 Is `amount` the transaction amount?

Comment: Yes. Amount is the value entered by the user to be subtracted from the balance

Comment: @user3057816 Okay. All you have to do is store that in a vector. So make a vector `std::vector<int> v;` and when the user enters in `amount`, do `v.push_back(amount)`. I'll show you how to print the vector in my answer.

Comment: @user3057816 I'm glad I was able to help! Also, don't forget to accept my answer by clicking the checkmark. :)